# Is echelon form a requirement to show a matrix has no solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do I need to get a matrix into echelon form to prove that it has no solutions, or do I only need a pivot in the last column. For example, would the following row operation show that there are no solutions to the linear system represented that by the augmented matrix below?

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0&5\\-1&1&5&2\\-1&1&5&3\end{bmatrix}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0&5\\-1&1&5&2\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What entry did you pivot on?

Comment: I'm not sure what definition of pivot you are using. By pivot, I mean the "leading entry in a row".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your transformation suffices; if you translate your matrix back into a system of linear equations, the last row gives the equation $0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot y + 0 \cdot z = 1$.

This is indeed the beauty of the representation of systems of linear equations as matrices: you perform simple operations on the rows of the matrix but preserve the solution set of the original system. At the end, you just read off the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not required. Once you've performed row operations (as you have) to a point where you reach an inconsistency, you can conclude the system has no solutions. Going all the way to echelon form, or rref, won't change that.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to prove the matrix of the homogeneous part and the augmented matrix do not have the same rank. In the present case, what you've done is enough: the matrix of the homogeneous part (first $3$ columns) has rank $2$ and the augmented matrix has rank $3$.